# Vim: Completion menu item colors

Tags: vim, autocomplete

Vim's completion features include an option to distinguish between different types.
I'm now in the process of writing my own autocompletion. Therefore I like to colorize the entries differently, with a color for each type.

This should be possible, as the Vim documentation notes:

> The "kind" item uses a single letter to indicate the kind of
>   completion.  This   may be used to show the completion differently
>   (different color or icon). Currently these types can be used:
>
> ```
>     v       variable 
>     f       function or method     
>     m       member of a struct or class        
>     t       typedef                              
>     d       #define or macro
> ```

This   may be used to show the completion differently(different color or icon). `How?` I did not find anything in the Vim help. The highlight settings for the menu (hl-PMenu) seem to be only for the whole menu, not for different types.

The completion looks like this at the moment (the letter behind is the type:

```
variable1          v
str()              f
```

All menu items have the same color.

Comment: +1 That would definitely be neat, but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/28561/how-to-use-colored-icons-for-autocomplete-menu-nvim-coc

Answer (score 0):

I normally flick through [jellybeans](https://github.com/nanotech/jellybeans.vim) as a reference as it's quite complete (and the author is quite receptive to pull requests)